# Python: Assertion using repr method is failing

Tags: python

I have the following class:

```
class Heart(Organ):
    def __init__(self
                , heart_length_cm
                , heart_weight_grams
                , heart_thickness_cm
                , heart_breadth_cm
                ):
        #Declaring public attributes of Heart class    
        self.heart_length_cm = heart_length_cm
        self.heart_weight_grams = heart_weight_grams
        self.heart_thickness_cm = heart_thickness_cm
        self.heart_breadth_cm = heart_breadth_cm
        
        #Calling parent class using super()
        super().__init__(__class__.__name__
                         , self.heart_weight_grams
                         , True
                         , 'Muscular')
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return ("The {organ_name} is an important part of the body that "
                "weighs {weight} grams and measures {length} cm in length "
                ", {breadth:,.1f} cm in breadth "
                "and {thickness:,.1f} cm in thickness."\
                .format(organ_name = __class__.__name__
                        , weight = self.heart_weight_grams
                        , length = self.heart_length_cm
                        , breadth = self.heart_breadth_cm
                        , thickness = self.heart_thickness_cm
                        )
                )
    
    def heart_status(self):
        '''This function returns the heart's status'''  
        return 'pumping blood'
    
    def heart_weight_oz(self):
         '''This function converts the heart's weight from grams to ounces'''      
         return round(self.heart_weight_grams*0.035, 2)
```

I created an instance of heart class using the following:

```
heart_length = 12
heart_weight = 280
heart_thickness = 6.0
heart_breadth = 9.0

brain_volume = 1260
brain_weight = 1370.0           

#Instantiating Heart and Brain classes
my_heart = Heart(heart_length
                 , heart_weight
                 , heart_thickness
                 , heart_breadth)
```

However, the following assertion is failing:

```
assert my_heart == repr(my_heart),\
"The heart message doesn't match\n {} \n\n {}"\
.format(my_heart, repr(my_heart))
```

Why is this failing? how do I fix this issue? Sorry I am quite new to repr method and would appreciate guidance.

This is the error message:

```
AssertionError: The heart message doesn't match
 The Heart is an important part of the body that weighs 280 grams and measures 12 cm in length , 9.0 cm in breadth and 6.0 cm in thickness. 

 The Heart is an important part of the body that weighs 280 grams and measures 12 cm in length , 9.0 cm in breadth and 6.0 cm in thickness.
```

Comment: `my_heart == repr(my_heart)` doesn't make sense, one's a `Heart` (with no `__eq__` method) and one's a string. Assert against the expected string, `repr(my_heart) == "..."`.

Comment: Why do you expect an object to be equal to its `repr`? it doesn't make any sense. Even a string object is not equal to its own `repr`. `'a' == repr('a')` is `False`